# Почему вывод не работает?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, странно то если делаю выводи с ограничением по id тогда выводит, а с email почему то нет.
Вот код:

```
$gig = 'sadas@mail.ru';
$history = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE email = ".$gig);
$userH=mysql_fetch_array($history);
echo $userH['name'];
echo $gig;
```

Comment: потому что должно быть `email='sadas@mail.ru'`, в апострофах

Comment: @vp_arth а если мне нужно брать sadas@mail.ru с переменной ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки в запросах должны быть в апострофах.

```
$gig = 'sadas@mail.ru';
$gig = mysql_real_escape_string($gig);
$history = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE email = '$gig'");
$userH=mysql_fetch_array($history);
echo $userH['name'];
echo $gig;
```

---

[mysql_](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

> **Внимание:** Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или
>   [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Смотрите также инструкцию [MySQL: выбор API](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) и
>   [соответствующий FAQ](http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) для получения более подробной информации.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что надо строки обрамлять апострофами:

```
$history = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE email = '". $gig ."'");
```